# How to stop printing half of my print method

Tags: java, class, inheritance, superclass

I just need some assistance in stopping the print method. its printing my output twice as car1.print(); car2.print(); is in the print method at the bottom. how do i exclude this without deleting it. It has to be put in the super.print() part.

```js
class Vehicle {  // base class

   int capacity;
   String make;

   Vehicle(int theCapacity, String theMake) {
      capacity = theCapacity;
      make = theMake;
   }

   void print() {
      System.out.println("Vehicle Info:");
      System.out.println("  capacity = " + capacity + "cc" );
      System.out.println("  make = " + make );
   }
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
   public String type;
   public String model;

   public Car(int theCapacity, String theMake, String theType, String theModel) {
      super(theCapacity, theMake); 
      type = theType;
      model = theModel;
      
      super.print(); 
      {
         System.out.println("  type = " + theType);
         System.out.println("  Model = " + theModel);
      }
   }
}


class Task1 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Car car1 = new Car(1200,"Holden","sedan","Barina");
      Car car2 = new Car(1500,"Mazda","sedan","323");
      car1.print();
      car2.print();
   }
}
```

Comment: The official docs have an example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html You will have to be clearer about your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `super` keyword in the constructor to invoke the super class' constructor and pass parameters to it.
Note that it must be the first statement in the constructor:

```
class Car extends Vehicle {
   public String type;
   public String model;


   public Car(int theCapacity, String theMake, String theType, String theModel) {
      super(theCapacity, theMake); // Here
      type = theType;
      model = theModel;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `Constructor`

```
public Car (int theCapacity, String theMake, String theType, String theModel) {
  capacity = theCapacity;
  make = theMake;
  Type = theType;
  Model = theModel;
}
```

or

```
public Car (int theCapacity, String theMake, String theType, String theModel) {
  super (theCapacity, theMake);
  Type = theType;
  Model = theModel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call super constructor by passing simply parameters in child class.

```
public Car(int capacity, String make, String type, String model) {
      super(capacity, make); // simply call super
      this.type = type;
      this.model = model;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution is calling your base class Constructor from child class using super keyword and adding other parameters from child class constructor as mentioned by @Mureinik

Depending on the requirements of the Base Class you can also try using abstract methods. Example code is below.

```
abstract class Vehicle {

   static int capacity;
   static String make;

   Vehicle(int theCapacity, String theMake) {
      capacity = theCapacity;
      make = theMake;
   }

   protected static void print() {
      System.out.println("Vehicle Info:");
      System.out.println("  capacity = " + capacity + "cc" );
      System.out.println("  make = " + make );
      // you can use these methods where you want in this base class.
      System.out.println("  type = " + getType());
      System.out.println("  model = " + getModel());

   }
   protected abstract  String getType();
   protected abstract  String getModel();
}


public class Car extends Vehicle{

    Car(int theCapacity, String theMake) {
        super(theCapacity, theMake);
    }
/**
 * @param args
 */
    public static void main(){

        print();
    }

    @Override
    protected String getType() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "Audi";
    }
    @Override
    protected String getModel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "Q7";
    }

    }
```